# jQuery calculate visible table columns only

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

It would be so nice if someone could help me on this:

https://jsfiddle.net/vloryan/rhgana61/

```
$('tr').ready(function() {
    $(this).find('span.avg-peter').html($('td.peter-a', this).val() * $('td.peter-b', this).val());
});
```

I have a with several columns, those visible (blue and yellow) should be used in my calculation. The last (yellow) column should show the average value of the visible blue and visible yellow column. When I change the blue or yellow column the value in the red column should of course change.

Puh! This is so hard for me. I couldn't even get the sum of the first blue columns (A&B) to the X column.

It would be awesome!

Comment: Is it, blue -> X and yellow -> Y AND red ->avg of X & Y, am I right ?

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I just corrected the fiddle. RED is the AVG of the currently visible blue and yellow.

Comment: Thats what you want, or something else ?

Comment: Yes, but I can't get the average of A & B to X and C & D to Y as well. I just can't :( That's what I need first. And then the AVG of A or B or X AND C or D or Y depending on what column is visible. Oh my god, thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go through the tr / td of your table and select the appropriate class, also using `val()` alone won't help you, you have to use `parseInt()` and `parseFloat()` , here is a working fiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/whos78nq/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Holy! This is awesome, thank you so much! Thank you Thank you Thank you! If you got two more seconds left: can you tell how I can "Math.floor" the calculated average values, before I destroy your beautiful fiddle :)

Comment: `peter_avg = Math.floor(peter_avg);` did it. Is that a correct solution in your opinion?

Comment: cool, you can also change all `parseFloat(value).toFixed(2)` calls to `Math.floor(value)`, updated fiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/qcqveeo5/

Comment: Thank you so much! You made my day!

Comment: Knock knock. Sorry, me again. Why are columns X and Y visible by default? Shouldn't A, C and Z be visible according to the CSS? How can I change the current fiddle to A, C and Z visible?

Comment: it's because the table is updated via a simulated click.. at the end of the js code, change `$('.mdl-menu__item').click();` to `$('.mdl-menu__item:first').click();` , this will it will do the trick but just as the 'Column A' was clicked (so you can keep the original displayed collumns A, C and Z)

Comment: While the linked solution may well work, I'm down-voting this answer because it combines a very low quality approach with a link-only format. Should that resource be deleted, or should JS Fiddle reorganise their content, this answer will become almost entirely useless.